# Using the hash in a function argument with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Currently, I am working CoffeeScript and I need to be able to pass options into an argument and have them be run in the function.

In ruby, I would do something like this:

```
def some_method(options = {})
  options.each do |key, value|
    puts "the #{key} key has a value of #{value}"
  end
end

some_method(hello: "world", something: "else")
```

How would I go about doing in this in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the coffee doc.

- Functions and default parameters http://coffeescript.org/#literals
- Loop http://coffeescript.org/#literals

  for key, value of obj

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is as simple as it gets:

```
some_method = (options) ->
  alert "the #{key} key has a value of #{value}" for key, value of options

some_method hello: "World", something: "else"
```

To ease the transition from ruby to coffee, you could also separate the for loop like so:

```
some_method = (options) ->
  for key, value of options
    alert "the #{key} key has a value of #{value}"

some_method hello: "World", something: "else"
```